# Problems with WinToFlash

Tags: windows, usb-flash-drive

I can't create a bootable flash drive. Every Microsoft operating system I use, on boot shows:

> NTLDR is missing

I am using Novicorp WinToFlash 0.7.0010 beta but with no luck. Is there any other way to create a bootable flash drive?

**EDIT**
To fix this just use advanced mode and in format tab change format system (default FAT32 LBA) to FAT16 LBA, but now i have other problem, if file system you celected is FAT16 then program formats flash drive to 2 GB (I have 8 GB Kingston). So all Windows 7 files cannot be copied. Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Check out](http://www.intowindows.com/how-to-install-windows-7vista-from-usb-drive-detailed-100-working-guide/) How to create Bootable disk through command prompt and try with this hopefully you will not fail.
You can also see [Create bootable Usb](http://lavcopricetech.com/index.php?/topic/117-make-a-windows-7-usb-boot-drive-using-only-the-command-prompt-in-windows-7/)  through command prompt with full screen shots.
 Best of luck.

**Edit in response of comment**

*Use bootsect.exe in XP (it works!) and set the USB thumbdrive install as a /nt60 bootloader.
You can get bootsect.exe from the /boot folder in your Windows 7 media.
It won't work as fat32 as the source.wim is greater then 2GB. You need to format fs=ntfs.

In XP the following should work:

1) Format USB key as NTFS
2) Copy over Windows 7 files
3) Run bootsect.exe E: /nt60 (with E: being your USB thumbdrive letter).

Reboot. This should work.*

If it doesn't work try out the below link to download Microsoft Windows 7 USB/DVD Download Tool.
[Try out](http://kmwoley.com/blog/?p=345) here and you will get another download link for making bootable USB tool provided by Microsoft.

One more thing try another DVD image which should be error free, may be your DVD is scratched and the file is missing due to that so try it .

Comment: Diskpart isn't showing any flash drives. Just HDD.

Comment: Are you using Windows XP command prompt to make it bootable. If yes then diskpart command doesn't support USB drives in XP so you should have to try with Vista or Windows 7.